# Stack data structure in c explanation

Tags: c, data-structures

I came across this code on the net and didn't really understand it fully. Can someone please explain the push, pop, and peek parts in detail. These are the parts where most of my doubts are. Or, even better, if you could provide me with some links where data structures and pointers are taught in detail, it would be great.

```
// C program for array implementation of stack
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

// A structure to represent a stack
struct Stack
{
    int top;
    unsigned capacity;
    int* array;
};

// function to create a stack of given capacity. It initializes size of
// stack as 0
struct Stack* createStack(unsigned capacity)
{
    struct Stack* stack = (struct Stack*) malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    stack->capacity = capacity;
    stack->top = -1;
    stack->array = (int*) malloc(stack->capacity * sizeof(int));
    return stack;
}

// Stack is full when top is equal to the last index
int isFull(struct Stack* stack)
{   return stack->top == stack->capacity - 1; }

// Stack is empty when top is equal to -1
int isEmpty(struct Stack* stack)
{   return stack->top == -1;  }

// Function to add an item to stack.  It increases top by 1
void push(struct Stack* stack, int item)
{
    if (isFull(stack))
        return;
    stack->array[++stack->top] = item;
    printf("%d pushed to stack\n", item);
}

// Function to remove an item from stack.  It decreases top by 1
int pop(struct Stack* stack)
{
    if (isEmpty(stack))
        return INT_MIN;
    return stack->array[stack->top--];
}

// Function to get top item from stack
int peek(struct Stack* stack)
{
    if (isEmpty(stack))
        return INT_MIN;
    return stack->array[stack->top];
}

// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    struct Stack* stack = createStack(100);

    push(stack, 10);
    push(stack, 20);
    push(stack, 30);

    printf("%d popped from stack\n", pop(stack));

    printf("Top item is %d\n", peek(stack));

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not contain any specific problem and demands existing code explanation.

Comment: 'I came across this code on the net' - please provide link to where you found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a great page to read ...

http://www.c4learn.com/data-structure/basic-stack-concept/

I can not take snippets from it - as it's full of images and done in a good way to fully understand stacks and how they work.

This will then allow you get to grips with the code you posted in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Think you wake up one morning an mom has made pancakes for breakfast..You settle down on the table and you have an empty plate **(empty stack)**. Mom was in a good mood today so she is making pancakes with numberson them.

Mom then puts only one pan cake on the plate with number 2 **(one push in the stack)**. Then you demand that you are hungry and ask more. She puts another pancake, but since there is one pancake on the plate already, she can only put the new pancake above it **(another push in the stack)**. You still think you can eat more, so you keep asking, and mom keeps giving pancakes, putting on above the other, and the last pancake was numbered 10.

Now, when you start eating. You noticed that you can only eat the last pancake that your mom gave, numbered 10. So you look at it, and eat it **(pop from the stack)**. So, you go on eating the pancakes in the reverese order in which mom gave, since you can access the pancakes in **LIFO** order.

And that my friend, is stack for you.

Comment: Haris, that's funny - however, as a child I was only allowed two pancakes! Maybe in the 70s water and flour was really expensive! Does Mom supply lemon juice and sugar also? :-)

Comment: @Neil.. Yup, a `heap` of sugar, a `bucket` of lemon juice, and an `array[7]` of love, for each day of the week.. :)